# How to use an object property as @Input binding in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, input

I'm new in Angular and Ionic Frameworks, so I'm practicing first. I have a trouble with a basic `@Input`testing where basically I'm looping trought an array of Tab Pages and then I want to render each tab with `<ion-tab>`. Here is my code:

*tabs.html*

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab *ngFor="let page of tabPages" [root]="page.root" [tabTitle]="page.title">
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

*tabs.ts*

```
import { Component }    from '@angular/core';

// - - - Pages Components - - - //
import { AboutPage }    from '../about/about';
import { ContactPage }  from '../contact/contact';
import { HomePage }     from '../home/home';
import { SettingsPage } from "../settings/settings";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tabPages : Array<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.tabPages = [];

    this.tabPages.push( { root : HomePage, title : "Home" } );
    this.tabPages.push( { root : AboutPage, title : "About" } );
    this.tabPages.push( { root : ContactPage, title : "Contact" } );
    this.tabPages.push( { root : SettingsPage, title : "Settings" } );
  }
}
```

So my question is there's a way to bind a property from an object and used it as Input for a component?

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is possible,

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let page of tabPages" >
  <ion-tab [root]="page.root" [tabTitle]="page.title">
  </ion-tab>
</ng-container>
```

and your child component should have something like,

```
@input root: string;
@input tabTitle: string;
```

Comment: Wow thanks mister, it works!. By the way I had to use this referenced answer to understand the `<ng-container>`